# How to move items between two jlists with add remove buttons

Tags: java, jbutton, jlist

I have been given the task to create a GUI that has a two `JLists` (left and right) and to be able to move items between the two lists using add and remove buttons.

Once added to the right list the item should no longer show in the left list. How do I make these buttons perform the correct actions?

Please see my code below:

```
            JList<String> leftList = new JList<String>();
            leftList.setModel(new AbstractListModel<String>() {
                String[] values = new String[] {"Car", "Truck", "Boat", "Plane"};
                public int getSize() {
                    return values.length;
                }
                public String getElementAt(int index) {
                    return values[index];
                }
            });
            leftList.setBounds(0, 0, 196, 539);
            frame.getContentPane().add(leftList);

            JList<String>rightList = new JList<String>();
            rightList.setBounds(285, 0, 196, 539);
            frame.getContentPane().add(rightList);


    //this will create the add and remove buttons
            JButton btnAddButton = new JButton(">>");
            btnAddButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {

                }
            });
            btnAddButton.setBounds(218, 247, 49, 34);
            frame.getContentPane().add(btnAddButton);





            JButton btnRemoveButton = new JButton("<<");
            btnRemoveButton.setBounds(218, 292, 49, 34);
            frame.getContentPane().add(btnRemoveButton);


}
```

Comment: Consider asking separate questions for the positioning and the responding for actions and give a little overview over your research.

Answer (score 0):

checkout List Demo

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/displayCode.html?code=https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/components/ListDemoProject/src/components/ListDemo.java

guideline:

you should not use local variable, since once method is over they all will disappear and only way to get them back is through

```
((JComponent)frame.getContentPane().getComponent(n)).getComponent(n)
```

I refer to both your "GUI" and

```
String[] values;
```

You shouldn't have used "String[] values" at all, since array has a fixed size, thus you can't modify it, use ArrayList.

in this particular case you shouldn't use Array or List at all, keep reading...

You should not be precise when you developing GUI, since graphic optimization mechanism gonna crumble it at the end, thus instead of using "AbstractListModel" you should have tried "DefaultListModel"

(i honestly tried to do your example with "AbstractListModel" and in the "leftListModel", getElementAt() method was called only once , and every farther revalidate() and repaint() don't give any result)

Since now we using DefaultListModel there is no need of any array, instead there is "addElement()"